# JMetter, Encrypt requests, decrypt responses

Tags: jmeter

The system encrypts all requests and returns encrypted data. How can I encrypt all requests and decrypt responses? Also, can I load the JSON body of the request with the parameters from the file, something like:

```
{"Token":${token}, "SomeParam": ${somevalue}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption/decryption should be possible using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) correspondingly, JMeter comes with [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library which provides handy APIs for encryption/decryption of data using various algorithms

With regards to loading request parameters from the file containing nested JMeter Variables go for [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) functions combination like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(your_file.json,,)})}
```

Check out [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) for more information.